# Python & Kivy - Show / Hide Box

Tags: python, input, kivy, screen, textinput

I built an app which is taking photo and goes to another empty screen and runs my main code on the background. I want to show a text input box in the  empty screen while my main code is in its 1st if condition; and hide the box while the code is in 2nd if condition. My code is in below. I wrote "blablabla"s for unnecessary long things for my question.

```
class CheckScreen(Screen):
    def deneme(self):

    #MY MAIN CODE
    #...

        if(BLABLABLA)
            self.isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)
        else
            self.isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(False)

GUI = Builder.load_string("""

#BLABLABLA1
#...

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.05
    multiline: False
<CheckScreen>:

    #BLABLABLA2
    #...

    SingleLineTextInput:
        opacity: 1 if root.isShownMenu else 0
""")

class TestCamera(App):

def build(self):
    return GUI

TestCamera().run()
```

While I'm running this, app always shows a textinput even I'm changing True to False in conditions. Where is my problem?

Comment: Did you check if the `if - else` conditions work? Have you tried putting some `print` statements in each conditions?

Comment: yes i'm so sure because my main code works without app

Comment: Try changing `self.isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)` to just `self.isShownMenu = True` and likewise for False

Answer (score 0):

Your BooleanProperty needs to be defined at the class level:

```
class CheckScreen(Screen):
    isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)
```

Use `True` or `False` as desired. Then in your code just reference `self.isShownMenu`, like:

```
    if(BLABLABLA)
        self.isShownMenu = True
    else
        self.isShownMenu = False
```